# Stop another .then() execution in chain of promises

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

I have programme in nodejs & mysql like below

```
db.query()
   .then(1)
   .then(2)
   .then(3)
   .catch()
```

I am checking a value from database in `then(1)` and trying to return response from there.In `then(2)` , I am executing another code that uses some data from result of `then(1)`  and so on..

**My problem:** When returning response from `then(1)`, `catch()` is calling(because `then(2)` have error, not getting data from `then(1)`) . So is there any way I can stop further execution in `then(1)` so that `then(2)` and `catch()` couldn't call ?

```
db.query('query......', [val1, val2])
.then(rslt => { return res.json({ mssg: "Email already exists!", error: "Email already exists!" }) }) 
.then(user => { return db.query('INSERT INTO ', value, (err, res, flds) => { err ? reject(err) : resolve(res) }) })
.then(user => { return res.json({ mssg: "Success", success: true}) })
.catch( (err) => { console.log(err) })
```

Comment: May I see how you returned responses from then(1) to then(2)?

Comment: `db.query('query......', [val1, val2])  
  
  .then(rslt => {  

    
     return res.json({ mssg: "Email already exists!", error: "Email already exists!" })  

   })  
   .then(user => {  
     return db.query('INSERT INTO ', value, (err, res, flds) => {  
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)  
            })  

   })  
    .then(user => {  
     return res.json({ mssg: "Success", success: true})   
   })  
    .catch( (err) => {  
     console.log(err)  
    })`

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) use an async function, instead of using the lower-level `.then()` API of the Promise object:

```
async function doTheThing() {
  try {
    const result = await db.query('...');
    if (result) { // user exists
      return res.json({...}); // this will end the entire function
    }
    const user = await db.query('...');
    return res.json({...}); // success
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err); // I don't recommend doing this. try/catch should be for recovery
  }
}
```